# Use grep to write gpspipe data

Tags: linux, grep, nmea

I am trying to use the gpspipe tool to create a file output of latitude and longitude data from a usb receiver I have plugged in. All I am interested in is the latitude and longitude (and potentially speed), so I have constructed the current line of code isolating the GPPA lines (which have this info).

```
gpspipe -r -t -o test.txt | grep GPPA
```

However this just writes all the NMEA data directly to the file skipping the grep command, I assume this is as the -o is presented first, however neither of the following lines work either.

```
gpspipe -r -t | grep GPPA | gpspipe -o test.txt
gpspipe -r -t | grep GPPA | > test.txt
```

The former fails to run and the latter writes a blank file, this is the first real project I am undertaking using linux so am a little unsure on command construction, is it possible to get the output I want i.e. a line by line .txt file of only the GPPA lines?

Answer (score 1):

You almost got the solution:

```
gpspipe -r -t | grep "GPPA" > test.txt
```

Obviously, this only works when this command gives you the results you're looking for:

```
gpspipe -r -t | grep "GPPA"
```

If not, just launch `gpspipe -r -t` and check for the presence of `GPPA` in the results. When you're dealing with capitals and small letters, you might use `grep -i "GPPA"` for working in a case insensitive way.

In case you have issues with file permissions, you might make sure the file exists and then launch the following command:

```
gpspipe -r -t 2>&1 | grep "GPPA" >> test.txt
```

1. The `2>&1` makes sure that ALL output (normal output and error output) is redirected to the output file.
2. The `>>` adds the information to the already existing file.

Comment: Unfortunately when I run that it also just writes a blank .txt file, gpspipe has a specific -o option for writing to file so I am not sure if that is interfering. But running the line as stated without the "> test.txt" produces the exact output I want in the terminal.

Comment: @GKelly: I've added some explanation.

Comment: So the command `gpspipe -r -t | grep "GPPGA"` produces an output in the terminal that is exactly what I want, GPGGA info line by line. However with the addition of the `> test.txt` nothing is written to the file, this is what the issue seems to be.

Comment: @GKelly: ... and what now, with the latest modifications?

Comment: @GKelly: I see an upvote. Things are getting better? :-)

Comment: unfortunately this still just produces a blank text file, but the discussion has been very enlightening still!

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions to that file? Please check your user/group and the permissions of that file and the current directory.

Comment: Yes I've checked and I have permission for that file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252654/discussion-between-gkelly-and-dominique).